# Why does this not create a JIRA issue?

Tags: python, api, rest, jira, pycharm

```
from jira.client import JIRA
import requests
import jira.exceptions
import json
import re

class MyJira(JIRA):

    def _create_http_basic_session(self, username, password):
        url = self._options['server'] + '/rest/auth/1/session'
        payload = {
            'username': username,
            'password': password
        }
        verify = False
        self._session = requests.session(verify=verify,
            hooks={'args': self._add_content_type})
        r = self._session.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
        jira.exceptions.raise_on_error(r)

options = {'server':'http://localhost:8080',
           'verify': False}
username = 'usrName'
password = 'passWord'

basic_auth =(username,password)
jira = MyJira(options, basic_auth)

issue_dict = {
    'project':{'key':'PROJKEY'},
    'summary': 'New Issue from jira-python',
    'description': 'Test Description for new issue created from jira-python',
    'issueType': {'name': 'Bug'}}

new_issue = jira.create_issue(fields=issue_dict,preftech=True)
print new_issue.id
```

this produces me this error stacktrace/log

```
/home/ve/bin/python/home/PycharmProjects/RestJira/restjira.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/RestJira/myrestjira.py", line 81, in <module>
    new_issue = jira.create_issue(fields=issue_dict,preftech=True)
  File "/home/ve/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 369, in create_issue
    raise_on_error(r)
  File "/home/ve/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jira/exceptions.py", line 29, in raise_on_error
    error = errorMessages[0]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

what am I doing wrong? I don't understand why there is a reference to another file(restjira.py) other than the one I am currently working in (myrestjira.py)
I am using python 2.7, jira-python library, requests 0.14.1, jira-python 0.12 and pycharm as an IDE
Anyone?

Comment: Could you fix your indentation? Everything in the `MyJira` class needs to be indented, but I'm not 100% what you meant to be in the class.

Comment: Based on how he's using the class, I think it is fairly safe to say that the only thing in `MyJira` is the definition of `_create_http_basic_session`

Comment: @cwallenpoole Okay, I indented only that one method.

Comment: apologies for that. _create_http_basic_session is all that's in that class.

Comment: Does the script work if you don't extend the JIRA client, and just use it unchanged?

Comment: the answer is No. I inherit from jira and I only change a validate variable there to value False. but that is irrelevant. Following the documentation and examples of [readTheDocs](http://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) it should create a new issue but it doesn't ...

Answer (score 6):

Try this, it works ...

```
from jira.client import JIRA

jira_options={'server': 'http://jira-address'}
jira=JIRA(options=jira_options,basic_auth=('user','password'))

#Creating an issue:

new_issue = jira.create_issue(project={'key': 'key'}, summary='New issue from jira-   python',   description='Look into this one', issuetype={'name': 'Bug'})

# or creating issues using dict:

issue_dict = {
    'project': {'key': 'PROJ'},
    'summary': 'New issue from jira-python',
    'description': 'Look into this one',
    'issuetype': {'name': 'Bug'},
}
new_issue = jira.create_issue(fields=issue_dict)
```

Comment: Shilpi, For me it is throwing  response text = {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"labels":"Labels is required."}}

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with these two lines:

```
r = self._session.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
jira.exceptions.raise_on_error(r)
```

Your response to `self._session.post` is an error, but there is something wrong with the error received. This leads to a couple of questions.

- Can you confirm that your Jira server is up and running at `localhost:8080`?
- What happens if you `pprint(r)`?
- Are the username and password correct?
- is `self._session.verify` set to `False`?

As to why `restjira.py` is called, well, that is likely the module which loaded this module.

---

Some other thoughts:

- You should not name your variable `jira` unless you change `import jira.exceptions` to something like `import jira.exceptions as jiraexceptions`. It makes the code easier to read.
- `verify = False... verify=verify` is a bit extraneous. Why not just place `False` in the kwargs?